# Does Raku's NativeCall run "LocalFree( )"?

Tags: raku

Raku/Perl6, Windows 7 and 10

Does Raku's NativeCall run "LocalFree( )" after it creates buffers?  Or do I need to  do it myself?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localfree

Many thanks, -T

EDIT: this at JJ's request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexw

```
C++
    LSTATUS RegSetValueExW(
    HKEY        hKey,
    LPCWSTR     lpValueName,
    DWORD       Reserved,
    DWORD       dwType,
    const BYTE  *lpData,
    DWORD       cbData
  );
```

In assembly code:

```
 lea eax,[@@lMode]
 call RegSetValueExA,HKEY_CURRENT_USER,offset 
[@@VAL_Type],0,REG_DWORD,eax,DWORD
```

"offset [@@VAL_Type]" -> pointer to the keyvalue string buffer
"eax" -> pointer to the data (in the buffer "@@lMode")

"*lpData" and "@@lMode" are a buffers in an allocated space in memory.  After their use, their memory needs to be given back to the system with "LocalFree".

So to rephrase my question, when NativeCall allocated space in memory for buffers, does it consequently give back the space after it is done with it, or does it just leave it there (memory leak)?

So, do I need to call "LocalFree()" or does NativeCall take care of it for me?

Comment: You really need to clarify this question. Please post an example program, with output, and we might be able to come up with an answer. Although the short answer is probably no, NativeCall does not do anything for you other than offering a way to use native C functions and data structures.

Comment: JJ, see my edit in the original question

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Showing a snippet of Raku code that we can test with would be great.

Comment: Hi Håkon, I don't have my call to RegSetValueExW working yet.   I am still working on setting up C String and little endian for *lpData's buffer.  And, that is not actually why I am asking the question.  What I want to know is after I get my call to RegSetValueExW working properly, do I need to also call "LocalFree()" or not.    

By the way, the documentation is incorrect on converting a Raku string to a C String as it does not add a nul at the end.  

Would you like to see the code when I am finished?

Comment: My question is about the internal working of native call, not how to call RegSetValueExW

Comment: OT: Hi Håkon, I am working on my own paper describing how to use NativeCall with WinAPI calls.  It is over 300 lines and growing.  Not sure where to post it when I am done.  Git possibly.  Would you like a copy of that too?

Comment: Got RegSetValueExW working!  I still need this question answered as to if I need to call LocalFree.

Comment: I am throwing LocalFree anyway, just because.  It is not throwing an error.   This may be an bug in NativeCall resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: @Todd it's probably more confusing now. And the short answer is still No, NativeCall is just glue to call C code, so it does not call anything at all for you unless the C code does it.

Comment: In a way, that does make sense.  NativeCall would not know that a buffer needs to be closed.

Comment: @Todd *"Would you like a copy of that too?"* Thanks, that would be interesting to read yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already understand that...

- What NativeCall does is call C functions. It is *not* NativeCall's role to allocate or free memory.
- LocalFree is a C function. The normal way to call a C function from Raku is via NativeCall.

...then you can safely ignore this answer -- and the question to which this is an answer, and Todd's answer.

If you are *not* confident about the above, then perhaps this answer will clear up any confusion and reduce the chances you're misled. What I write in the following is pendatic. But I feel it's appropriate to ensure clarity.

> Does Raku's NativeCall run “LocalFree( )”?

Yes, if you tell it to.

NativeCall is the feature normally used to call C functions from Raku.<sup>1</sup>

> Does Raku's NativeCall run "LocalFree( )" after it creates buffers?

NativeCall does not create buffers of its own accord. All NativeCall does is call C functions as instructed by users' code.

Let's say you use NativeCall to call a C function that creates a buffer. Does that mean NativeCall created the buffer? Or did *you*? (In a similar vein, if one uses NativeCall to call LocalFree after one has used NativeCall to call a C function that creates buffers, does that mean the answer to Todd's question is Yes? And if not, does that mean the answer is No?)

You can use NativeCall to call [`LocalFree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localfree) because LocalFree is a C function, and calling C functions is precisely what NativeCall does when you use it to do something.<sup>2</sup>

> Or do I need to do it myself?

Depending on your answer to the parenthesized questions a couple paragraphs above...

Given that NativeCall does not create buffers, you *can't* need to do anything related to NativeCall creating buffers.

In the alternative, if NativeCall creates buffers, then it's because *you used it to manually call C functions that create buffers* and you therefore also need to manually call C functions to free those buffers if you want them freed.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> NativeCall is the Raku [C FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface).

<sup>2</sup> No matter what you "use" NativeCall for you would start with a `use NativeCall` statement. Then you would typically use it to call C functions. It's possible you might `use` it for access to nothing more than, say, some of the constants it defines.

Answer (score 0):

NativeCall does not close any WinApi call buffers, so you need to do it yourself.